Problems with cron job in node js and vercel
I need to create a feature so that a function is automatically executed once a day in my Node JS application.
I have a (very simple) test function that was implemented as follows:
//src/schedules/check-overdue-bills-to-pay/index.ts

import cron from "node-cron";

cron.schedule(
  "1 0 * * *",
  async () => {
    console.log("CRON OK");
  },
  {
    timezone: "America/Sao_Paulo",
  }
);

Here is index.ts, which the job is called for execution
//index.ts
import express from "express";

import { routes } from "./routes";
import "./schedules/check-overdue-bills-to-pay";

const app = express();

app.use(routes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT)

Locally it works. However, I need this job to run in vercel. To do this, I configured it in the vercel.json file
//vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": { "includeFiles": ["dist/**"] }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/index.js"
    }
  ],
  "crons": [
    {
      "path": "/dist/schedules/check-overdue-bills-to-pay/index.js",
      "schedule": "1 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}

Vercel Error:
Status Code:404 Not Found

Structure folders:

Does anyone know if I need to do any additional configuration in Vercel? Or do you recommend another way to implement this?
